# Consistent method to add id column to list elements

Tags: r, list, purrr, mapply

I am having trouble using `mapply` to add ID columns to lists (within a larger function).

With most lists the code below works fine...

```
m1 <- matrix(data = 1:32, nrow = 8, ncol = 4)
m2 <- matrix(data = 1:8, nrow = 2, ncol = 4)
m3 <- matrix(data = 1:16, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
m4 <- matrix(data = 1:4, nrow = 1, ncol = 4)
colnames(m1) <- colnames(m2) <- colnames(m3) <- colnames(m4) <- LETTERS[1:4]

a <- list(m1, m2, m3, m4)
mapply(cbind, a, m = 1:4)
# [[1]]
#      A  B  C  D m
# [1,] 1  9 17 25 1
# [2,] 2 10 18 26 1
# [3,] 3 11 19 27 1
# [4,] 4 12 20 28 1
# [5,] 5 13 21 29 1
# [6,] 6 14 22 30 1
# [7,] 7 15 23 31 1
# [8,] 8 16 24 32 1
# 
# [[2]]
#      A B C D m
# [1,] 1 3 5 7 2
# [2,] 2 4 6 8 2
# 
# [[3]]
#      A B  C  D m
# [1,] 1 5  9 13 3
# [2,] 2 6 10 14 3
# [3,] 3 7 11 15 3
# [4,] 4 8 12 16 3
# 
# [[4]]
#      A B C D m
# [1,] 1 2 3 4 4
```

but when I have lists that contain matrices of the same dimensions a list is no longer returned...

```
a <- list(m2, m2, m2, m2)
mapply(cbind, a, m = 2)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#  [1,]    1    1    1    1
#  [2,]    2    2    2    2
#  [3,]    3    3    3    3
#  [4,]    4    4    4    4
#  [5,]    5    5    5    5
#  [6,]    6    6    6    6
#  [7,]    7    7    7    7
#  [8,]    8    8    8    8
#  [9,]    2    2    2    2
# [10,]    2    2    2    2
```

I cannot find any explanation as to why this is happening or a possible workaround (where the output would be a list in a similar format to first example above)?

Comment: That is the difference between `mapply` and `Map`, `Map(cbind, a, m = 2)`. `mapply` has by default `simplify = TRUE` argument

Comment: @RonakShah ah perfect! many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly the difference between `mapply` and `Map`, `mapply` by default has `simplify = TRUE` argument which means

> SIMPLIFY - logical or character string; attempt to reduce the result to a vector, matrix or higher dimensional array; see the simplify argument of sapply.

Hence, in this case, to get output same as the first example we should use `Map`

```
Map(cbind, a, m = 2)

#[[1]]
#     A B C D m
#[1,] 1 3 5 7 2
#[2,] 2 4 6 8 2

#[[2]]
#     A B C D m
#[1,] 1 3 5 7 2
#[2,] 2 4 6 8 2

#[[3]]
#     A B C D m
#[1,] 1 3 5 7 2
#[2,] 2 4 6 8 2

#[[4]]
#     A B C D m
#[1,] 1 3 5 7 2
#[2,] 2 4 6 8 2
```